# How to leave imported property unchanged?

Tags: terraform

I have a hosted zone in the main.tf:

```
provider "aws" {
    region = "us-east-1"
}

resource "aws_route53_zone" "zone" {
}
```

I then can import an existing resource and use its parameters in other resources:

```
terraform import aws_route53_zone.zone <ZoneId>
```

Inspecting the state file I see the parameters are all there, including the domain name. But when I want to `apply` it it says that `name` is not found:

```
Error: aws_route53_zone.zone: "name": required field is not set
```

I don't want to specify the name in the `.tf` file as it would decrease the portability of my `.tf`, but specifying a placeholder would change the hosted zone itself.

Is there a way to ignore parameters for imported resources or specify them as "leave as-is"?

I could add a variable and populate that from the state file for every `terraform` calls, but I'm hoping for something simpler.

Comment: Can you post the exact error you get? And also include the complete Terraform code you are trying to plan/apply.

Comment: I've updated the question

Answer (score 0):

When you import a resource, Terraform doesn't (yet) automatically generate Terraform code for you and instead you must write the resource and then check the plan.

Normally the pattern would be to create a skeleton resource like you've done, import the resource and then fill out any required fields, run a plan, then adjust your resource configuration so that it doesn't make any unwanted changes.

From then on Terraform will be able to manage the resource as normal, applying any changes you make to the configuration or reverting changes done outside of Terraform back to how they are done in your Terraform code.